# Evaluate limits

Tags: limits

> Evaluate $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(\ln x)^n}x$, where $n\in\Bbb N$.

I think $(\ln x)^n$ & $x$ is positive infinity when $x$ goes positive infinity
so use a L'Hospital's theorem

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Why not try to work out what you get if you apply l'Hopital/show some effort?

Comment: Welcome to the website. Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your math formulae in future. Did you try to solve it using L'Hospital's Rule? You're on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply L'Hoptial's rule n-times,

$$L  = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(\ln x)^n}{x} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(n\ln x)^{n-1}}{1\cdot x} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{n(n-1)(\ln x)^{n-2}}{1\cdot x} = \cdots =\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{n!(\ln x)}{x} = \cdots$$

Can you apply for the last step?

Answer (score 1):

**Note that**
As $x\to\infty$ $\ln x $ increases much slower than an positive power of $x$.
Using this statement we directly find the limit 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(\ln x)^n}{x} $$
$$=0$$

Answer (score 1):

Just by substitution, without L'Hospital's rule:

Set $x=y^n$. Then
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(\ln x)^n}x=\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac{(\ln y^n)^n}{y^n}=n^n\lim_{y\to\infty}\Bigl(\frac{\ln y}y\Big)^n=n^n\cdot 0.$$